# When I open Google Chrome it always also opens a tab for ChatGPT extension on the Chrome Web Store for extensions, how do I make it stop?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

As I said in the title when I open Chrome I am welcomed by the start page but I also have this new tab open for this extension [UseChatGPT.AI: ChatGPT Copilot for the Web](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/usechatgptai-chatgpt-copi/mhnlakgilnojmhinhkckjpncpbhabphi). It seems legit and I doubt it's fake but it's just annoying and I would like it to stop.

edit: I did just remove 1 extension I recently added it might have solved itself but if you recognize the issue your answers are welcome.

Comment: "It seems legit"? It's a random extension by a random developer not affiliated with OpenAI.

Comment: Also perhaps undo what you did. No issue with Chrome here.

Answer (score 2):

[Based on this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/12au4o5/suspicious_chatgpt_extension/) there's been a few different offenders, but one that is mentioned a few times is the ModHeader Extension:

- [ModHeader Extension Chrome Webstore Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader-modify-http-hea/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj)
- [ModHeader Extension Homepage](https://modheader.com/)

From the reddit thread:

> I'll comment on this old thread as it's a top google hit.
>
> The ModHeader extension was my cause, they've recently partnered with MaxAI.me and so decided to push this on their users. Feels like an own goal for them, as now they're being review bombed and uninstalled.

(*From user [thewoodfather](https://www.reddit.com/user/thewoodfather/)*)

I just got this symptom and I have this extension installed, but I'm having trouble consistently recreating it; I'll continue to test, and if I am able to confirm that removal of ModHeader resolves the issue I'll update here.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted - seems to be the culprit in my case

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the Chrome extension of
[UseChatGPT.AI: ChatGPT Copilot for the Web](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/usechatgptai-chatgpt-copi/mhnlakgilnojmhinhkckjpncpbhabphi).

To remove it :

- Open Chrome
- Enter the address `chrome://extensions/`
- Locate the extension named `UseChatGPT.AI`
- Click the Remove button, or disable it by moving the little blue slide
  to the Off position.